# Recover Original Windows after installing another version?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, system-recovery

I have a laptop(Lenevo Yoga 500). It comes with Windows 8.1 Single Language. Can I Install Windows 8.1 Pro in my laptop having recovery option of windows 8.1 single language to Revert to my original windows (In Case).
﻿

Answer (score 0):

You can back up your current installation on another disk if you have enough space. Check out CloneZilla for that, it is free: [clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org/)